# 'qunit' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, qunit

I installed qunit, using command:

```
npm install -g qunit
```

Then, I wrote a test program and named the file as firstTest.js. The contents of firstTest.js is:

```
module.exports = {  
    'should run test': function(t) {  
        t.printf("running test!\n");  
        t.done();  
    },  
};
```

On executing command:

```
qunit firstTest.js
```

I got 'qunit' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 
What should I do ?

Comment: Please see `%APPDATA%\npm`, is there a file named `qunit.cmd` in this directory?

Comment: No, I did not find any file named as `qunit.cmd`

Comment: When you run `qunit` in command line, it actually refers to `qunit.cmd` in `%APPDATA%\npm`. If you don't have this file, you can't run `qunit` in command line. Try to reinstall `qunit` module.

Comment: Thanks @MartinZhai

Answer (score -2):

Okay, so first off, that is not how you write a QUnit test. You can read the [documentation here](https://qunitjs.com/), but essentially you need to write code that a browser can interpret, and `module.exports` is not a browser object, it's only in Node.

Now, if you are using some other Node module that let's you write tests that way, cool! But if you are using the base `qunit` module you can't write tests that way. Here's how you can write that test in proper QUnit:

```
QUnit.test("should run test", function( assert ) {
  console.log("running test!");
  assert.ok(1 === 1, "one equal one");
});
```

Now you need to load that test file in an HTML file and open it in the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>QUnit Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.1.1.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Second, **QUnit does not have a CLI executable program** bundled with it. You will need to use another module to run that test from the command line. Something like the task runner [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) combined with the [grunt-contrib-qunit](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-qunit) plugin.