# Unable to install qunit using npm

Tags: windows, qunit

I was trying to install **"qunit"** using Windows command Prompt by executing the command
`"npm i qunit"`.
On executing , it loads something and then it does not show anything . I have to press Ctrl+C twice to stop whatever this command is executing in the background.
Because of this "qunit" is not getting installed properly.
How should i resolve this problem ?

Comment: Could you post the error that you're getting or the output when you run the command?

Comment: No, it does not show any error or output. Read my problem again @Kenyanke

Comment: Have you tried waiting a couple of minutes for it to install? (because it's not instant)

Comment: Installing modules through command prompt through npm should not matter if you have your environment variables configured properly. I have done a fresh install of "npn i qunit" and though it worked, the installation took about 2 minutes.

Comment: Yes, I waited for long time. But did not get any response

Comment: Could you remove your node_modules folder and try to run the command again?

Comment: No, removing node_modules folder did not work

Comment: But when you run the command it creates an node_modules folder, but the install process is "Waiting" with a " | " flashing?

Comment: Can you run `npm i qunit --verbose` ? it will result in much more output (hopefully) and we might see where the problem lies. Look for any RED output.

Comment: Also, looking at the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802224/qunit-is-not-recognised-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-o) you posted, I'm not sure you realize what QUnit is and does. You should be installing `qunit` into a project, not globally. Then you use that project-local installation as the framework for your tests. Check out my answer over on that other question.

Comment: did not get any red output on executing 'npm i qunit --verbose'

Comment: I am installing qunit in project only not globally. But it is not getting installed